# Spring Boot Web RestTemplate Send Object as Query Param

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to make a POST request with URL Query Params set to the values of an object.

For example

```
http://test/data?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I want to make a post request to this URL with a class like this:

```
public class Data {
  private Integer a;
  private Integer b;
  private Integer c;
}
```

I do NOT want to do each field manually, like this:

```
public void sendRequest(Data data) {
  String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://test/")
    .queryParam("a", data.getA())
    .queryParam("b", data.getB())
    .queryParam("c", data.getC())
    .toUriString();

  restTemplate.postForObject(url, body, Void.class);
}
```

Instead, I want to use the entire object:

```
public void sendRequest(Data data) {
  String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://test/")
    .queryParamsAll(data) //pseudo 
    .toUriString();

  restTemplate.postForObject(url, body, Void.class);
}
```

Comment: Check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-post-json

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is like QS in js. Thx [qianshui423/qs](https://github.com/qianshui423/qs) . It is implementation QS in java. It is coded by a Chinese guy. At first git clone it and use below cmd to build. You will get a jar called "qs-1.0.0.jar" in  build/libs (JDK required version 8)

```
# cd qs directory

./gradlew build -x test
```

Import it, I do a simple demo as below. For your requirement, you can build class to transfer your Obj into QSObject. Besides toQString, QS can parse string to QSObject. I think it powerful.

```java
import com.qs.core.QS;
import com.qs.core.model.QSObject;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        QSObject qsobj = new QSObject();
        qsobj.put("a",1);
        qsobj.put("b",2);
        qsobj.put("c",3);
        String str = QS.toQString(qsobj);
        System.out.println(str); // output is a=1&b=2&c=3
    }
}
```